# Prove vector spaces dimensions equality

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ a finite vector space over $F$, and $W$ a vector space over $F$ with the dimension of $1$. $S:V\rightarrow V, T:V\rightarrow W$ two linear transformations. It is given that $\ker S$ is not a subset of $\ker T$. Prove $\dim (\ker T \cap \ker S) = \dim (\ker S) - 1$

My Work:
using the Dimensions Thm we know that: $\def\Im{\operatorname{Im}}\dim V = \dim\ker T + \dim\Im T$. We know that $\ker S$ is not a subset of $\ker T$, Therefore there must be $S(x)=0$ and $T(x)\ne 0$. Therefore, the dimension of $\Im T$ isn't $0$, so it must be that $\dim\Im T=1$.

I tried to develop it further, but without much success.
I'll be glad for help.

### EDIT:

following Marc guidelines:
$$\begin{array}{l}
 U: = \ker S \\ 
 {T_U}:V \to V \\ 
 \dim U = \dim Ker{T_U} + \dim {\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} {T_U} \\ 
 \dim U = \dim Ker{T_U} + 1 \\ 
 \dim U - 1 = \dim Ker{T_U} \\ 
 \dim KerS - 1 = \dim Ker{T_U} \\ 
 \dim KerS - 1 = \dim KerT \cap \dim KerS \\ 
 \end{array}$$

Comment: You are correct with your previous work. Now try deducing the dimension of $\textrm{ker}T$ and from this and the fact, that $\textrm{ker}S$ is not a subset of $\textrm{ker}T$ the dimension of the intersection.

Comment: @sebigu, Can you tell me how to find $dimKerT$ please?

Comment: We have $\textrm{dim}V = \textrm{dim}\ \textrm{im} T + \textrm{dim}\ \textrm{ker}T$ by the homomorphism theorem. $T$ is surjective, and so the dimension of its image is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not wrong, but there is an easier way. Note that $S$ only serves to define $\ker S$, so setting $U=\ker S$ we can argue in terms of $U$ only. Since $U$ is not contained in $\ker T$, the restriction $T_U:U\to W$ of $T$ to the subspace $U$ is not the zero map. Now reason as you did in the question, but replacing $V$ by $U$ and $T$ by $T_U$ (you still get $\dim\Im T_U=1$).

Comment: Are you implying that:  
$$\dim Ker{T_U} = \dim KerT \cap \dim KerS$$

Comment: Yes, $\ker T_U=\ker T\cap U=\ker T\cap\ker S$.